# On the proof of sequentially compact subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

I don't understand last steps of proving the following theorem:

[image]

My questions are:

1- Why the statements "cover index $(x_{n_k}) \le$ cover index $(x_0)$ for each index $k \ge K$" or/and "cover index $(x_{n_k}) \ge n_k \ge k$ for all indices k", contradicts with the statement "cover index $(x_n) > n$ for every index n"?

2- In the text before the Figure 2.6. it supposes in $I_n$, n is finite and consider some J. But the 3rd line after Eq.2.28, ignore that fact and by assumption n can be infinite as well. Wrong assumption? On the other hand, If n can be infinite also when defined J (before the Figure 2.6.), cover index $(x_0)$ (which appears as upper bound thereafter) can also be infinite, makes the statements "cover index $(x_{n_k}) \le$ cover index $(x_0)$ for each index $k \ge K$" or/and "cover index $(x_{n_k}) \ge n_k \ge k$ for all indices k" nonsense. Wrong assumption again?

Thank you.

EDIT - I shrink the two above question to one and make it clearer (and $CI$ stands for cover index):

For every $n\in \mathbb N$, there is (at least) one point (name it $x_n$) in $S$ such that $CI(x_n)>n$. The sequence ${\{x_n}\}$ has a sub sequence ${\{x_{n_k}}\}$ such that limit of that sub sequence belongs to $S$; by limit we mean when $n_k\rightarrow \infty$, so in fact $x_0$ is a 'name' for $x_{\infty}$; since $CI(x_n)>n$ so $[CI(x_{\infty})=]\ CI(x_0)>\infty$. Thus $\infty=?CI(x_0)> CI(x_{n_k})\ge x_{n_k}\ge k$ holds no matter how large $k$ becomes. No contradiction, contrary to the statement of the book.

Comment: (1) is since $k$ is arbitrary so $\text{cover index}(x_{n_k})$ is bounded by the first property but not the second. If what you don't understand is the contradiction here.

Comment: The very first line in the proof: is it somehow trivial that sequentially compact sets are countably compact?

Comment: (2) What do you mean? The proof only talks about finite indexes. Since $x_0\in S$ it must be covered by some interval, since the intervals cover $S$, which is a finite index.

Comment: @simonzack - (2) we don't know if $S$ covered by finite number of intervals; we want to *prove* it, thus to prove that $S$ is compact. First assumption is that $S$ can be covered by infinite number of intervals. By (2), I mean what if $x_0\in I_\infty$ only? Then cover index $(x_0)=\infty$, which makes the rest of proof invalid.

Comment: @A.G. - I don't know about *countably* compact. I am studying from a very introductory book (Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick).

Comment: @AlphaE The proof starts with *Suppose that $(I_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a cover*. However, in the definition of compactness there is no assumption for the cover to be countable. Finite refinement for any countable cover does not proof compactness, only [countable compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space).

Comment: @AlphaE There is no $I_\infty$. Each set in the cover has a finite index.

Comment: @A.G. - I had a doubt also about that definition so I asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322320/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-a-cover-of-a-set), unfortunately no objections raised. Is there any simpler but true proof of the theorem (in real analysis not in topology)? Thank you

Comment: The first proof here is the same but written more concisely https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequentially_Compact_Metric_Space_is_Compact, I suppose the fact @A.G. mentions is not trivial.

Comment: @AlphaE It may be that the purpose of the book is to give you some intro to topology, and the author uses countable compactness. However, it should have been clarified from the beginning that it is not the real compactness as it is understood in topology. It is not good of the book to call things differently because it can confuse you in the future.

Comment: @simonzack - "There is no $I_∞$", the collection is $(I_n)_{n=1}^\infty$; yes it is not $..., \infty]$ but if it is covered by $(I_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and we still don't know it maybe covered by finite, so may still have some points not belong to $(I_n)_{n=1}^N$, no matter how big N we choose. Sorry I am very confused, why if we choose any number of 1,... still is finite when we say it goes to infinity? Thank you.

Comment: @AlphaE We don't yet know that $S$ has a finite subcover, but we do know that $x_0$ must belong to $S$, which has by assumption a countable cover, so $x_0$ must be in one of the sets $I_n$ by definition of set union. $(I_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is just a nice way of writing $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, you can think of it like a series sum, there is an infinity there but all elements have finite indexes.

Comment: @simonzack - Thank you very much for your comments. But I am sorry I still couldn't understand. I edit OP for more clear.

Comment: Sorry, a mistake: by "simple" in bounty box I mean simple enough to understand (i.e. clear).

Answer (score 2):

Markus Scheuer in his answer has analyzed the given proof and verified that it is correct. It cannot be denied that this proof has shortcomings, and above all, the introduction of the covering index function makes it more complicated than necessary.

According to the standard definition a set $S\subset{\mathbb R}$ is *compact* if any given family ${\cal I}=(I_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ of open intervals covering $S$ contains a finite subfamily $\bigl(I_{\alpha_k})_{1\leq k\leq N}$ covering $S$.

Assume now that $S\subset{\mathbb R}$ is sequentially compact and that we are given a covering of $S$ by a family ${\cal I}$ of open intervals $I_\alpha$.  I claim that *in any case* the family ${\cal I}$ contains a *countable* subfamily ${\cal J}=\bigl(I_{\alpha_k})_{k\geq1}$ covering $S$.

*Proof.* For each $x\in S$ there are an $\alpha_x\in I$ and two rational numbers $p_x$, $q_x$ with
$$x\in\ ]p_x,q_x[\ \subset I_{\alpha_x}\ .$$
The set ${\cal J}'$ of intervals $\ ]p_x,q_x[\ $ arriving in this way is countable. Select for each $J_k\in{\cal J}'$ an $x_k\in S$ with $J_k=\ ]p_{x_k},q_{x_k}[\ $, and put $\alpha_k:=\alpha_{x_k}$.$\quad\square$

Therefore we may now assume $S\subset \bigcup_{k\geq1} I_k$ with $I_k\in{\cal I}$ for all $k$. [This is the starting point in the quoted proof.]  Put $$U_n:=\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$ We shall show that there is an $N$ with $S\subset U_N$. Assume that this is not the case. Then for each $n\geq1$ we can find a point $x_n\in S\setminus U_n$. Since $S$ is sequentially compact there is a point $\xi\in S$ such that any neighborhood of $\xi$ contains points $x_n$ with arbitrarily large $n$. Now $\xi\in I_N$ for some $N$, and $I_N$ is a neighborhood of $\xi$. Therefore there   is an $x_n\in I_N\subset U_N$ with $n>N$, contradicting the definition of $x_n$.$\quad\square$

Comment: Very nice to provide an obviously superior alternative to the proof cited in OPs question and *really* good to indicate that the proof assumes that *$\mathbb{R}$* is countably compact. Your answer is an enrichment in clarifying OPs questions. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* It seems the proof is correct, but a somewhat misleading notation may cause confusion.

The author uses the variable $n$ *twice* in different context. The first time $n$ is used as bounded variable in the expression

\begin{align*}
  S\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^NI_n
  \end{align*}

In the paragraphs next to Figure 2.6 the variable $n$ is used in a different context. Maybe the things become easier comprehensible, when we analyse this text by using another variable name $m$ instead of $n$.

> If there is no natural number $N$ such that (2.26) holds, then for each natural number **$m$**, there is a point in $S$ whose cover index is greater than $m$; choose such a point and label it $x_m$. Thus, $\{x_m\}$ is a sequence in $S$ such that
>
> \begin{align*}
> \text{cover index}(x_m)>m\qquad\qquad \text{for every index }m.\qquad\qquad (2.28)
> \end{align*}

Here we assume *indirectly* that $S$ is not compact and therefore no representation like (2.25) is possible. If no finite cover exists, we find to each natural number $m$ and the corresponding subcover $S_m := \bigcup_{j=1}^mI_j$ a point $x_m$ which is not covered by $S_m$. This way   we obtain a sequence $\{x_m\}$ in $S$ explicitly constructed so that for each element $x_m$ its cover index is *greater* than $m$.

> But, by assumption the set $S$ is sequentially compact. Thus, there is a subsequence $\{x_{m_k}\}$ that converges to a point $x_0$ that also belongs to $S$. As noted above, we can choose an open interval $J$ centered at $x_0$ such that (2.27) holds. However, $x_0$ is the limit of the sequence $\{x_{m_k}\}$, so there is an index $K$ such that
>       \begin{align*}
>       x_{m_k} \text{ belongs to }J\text{ for each index }k\geq K.
>       \end{align*}

We consider the limit point
 \begin{align*}
   x_0:=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_{m_k}
   \end{align*}
 of the convergent subsequence $\{x_{m_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$. The notation $x_0$ is as suitable as $x_\infty$. We just need a symbol to uniquely identify the limit point of the subsequence.

This limit point $x_0$ is a point in $S$ and is therefore covered by $\bigcup_{j=1}^{M_0}I_j$ with $M_0$ being the cover index of $x_0$. We consider the interval $I_{M_0}$ and construct according to Figure 2.6 an interval $J_{M_0}$ centered around $x_0$ with

\begin{align*}
   x_0\in J_{M_0}\subseteq I_{M_0}
   \end{align*}

The clou: Since $x_0$ is the limit point of the  subsequence  $\{x_{m_k}\}$ all but finitely elements are in the Interval $J_{M_0}$. This implies that for all but finitely elements $x_{m_k}$ of this convergent subsequence their cover index is less than or equal $M_0$ and is therefore less than $m_k$ violating the construction principle of the sequence $\{x_{m}\}$.

**Summary:**

- (1) According to the indirect assumption that $S$ cannot by covered by a finite number of intervals, there is *for each* number $m$ an element $x_m\in S$ with a cover index $(x_m)>m$. On the other hand a convergent subsequence $\{x_{m_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ of the sequence $\{x_m\}_{m\geq 1}$ has all but finitely elements within one specific interval $I_{M_0}$ implying that the cover index of these elements $x_{m_k}$ is less or equal $M_0$. So, for all but finitely elements of $\{x_{m_k}\}$ is the cover index$(x_{m_k})\leq M_0<m_k$ which is a contradiction.
- (2) The variable $n$ is used twice in different context.

Comment: Your answer doesn't include my question at all. My question was the case for if cover index is $\infty$. The answer is that it's a wrong assumption cover index be $\infty$. Because if $CI(\text {some pt})=\infty$ it means that point is included in the 'last' coverage/interval which doesn't make sense because 1- intervals are open, 2- $J$ as a neighborhood of that point but still subset of some interval in the collection is none-sense, 3- contradiction to the concept of infinity.

Comment: @AlphaE: I've answered your questions (1) and (2) hopefully in the sense of your bounty text. Since the answer shows the author's proof is correct, this clearly implies your last assumption can't be valid. The main point on your last assumption is the wrong conclusion, that properties of the sequence elements in this case $CI(x_m) > m$ are also necessarily shared by the limit point. This is not the case. Think about a converging sequence consisting solely of positive elements. It does not necessarily follow that the limit point is greater zero, for example $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$.